# When ever I try to download a pdf with MVC it just open a blank page and does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, pdf

When I make this call it does return the content, the correct mime type, and the file name. It just wont download.

If anyone has an ideas on how to fix this, some help would be much appreciated.

```
public FileResult Download()
{
  if (HelperClass.SessionNotExpired(Session))
  {
    string caseNumber = Request.Params["CaseNumber"] as string;
    string fileName = Request.Params["FileName"] as string;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(caseNumber) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
      Document doc = DropBox.Get(caseNumber, fileName, DocumentServiceRequestCodes.WEB,          (string)Session[HelperClass.EMAIL], (string)Session[HelperClass.PASSWORD]);
      var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
      {
        // for example foo.bak
        FileName = doc.FileName,

        // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
        // the browser to try to show the file inline
        Inline = false,
      };
      Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

      return File(doc.Contents, GetMimeType(fileName), fileName);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `doc` is not NULL ?

Comment: What's the datatype of `doc.Contents`?

Comment: Not null and its an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If the Contents are a stream try and set its position manually?

`stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

or

`stream.Position = 0;`